# A case in which the lower Riemann integral is additive

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Let $A$ and $B$ be two open subsets of $[a,b]$.

I claim that

$$\underline {\int_a^b} \chi_A + \chi_B = \underline {\int_a^b} \chi_A + \underline {\int_a^b} \chi_B$$ where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of $A$.

Since the lower Riemann integral is superadditive, I should prove that $$\underline {\int_a^b} \chi_A + \chi_B \le \underline {\int_a^b} \chi_A + \underline {\int_a^b} \chi_B$$

Do I have to use the Heine-Borel theorem in some way ?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\underline{\int_{[a, b]}}(\chi_A+\chi_B)>\underline{\int_{[a, b]}}\chi_A+\underline{\int_{[a, b]}}\chi_B$, choose a partition $\mathcal{P}_1: a=t_0<t_1<\dots<t_n=b$ whose corresponding lower sum $L_1$(of $\chi_A+\chi_B$) lies between them.

Call an interval $[r, s]$ problematic if
$$\min_{[r, s]}(\chi_A+\chi_B)>\min_{[r, s]}\chi_A+\min_{[r, s]}\chi_B.$$

Observe that if $[r, s]$ is problematic, then every point of $[r, s]$ must be in one of $A, B$ and at the same time it contains points from $A\setminus B, B\setminus A$. In particular, the left side above should be $1$.

In the partition above, some $[t_i, t_{i+1}]$ should be problematic, else the lower sum of $\chi_A+\chi_B$ will be equal to the sum of lower sums of $\chi_A, \chi_B$. Let $P_1$ be the collection of problematic intervals in $\mathcal{P}_1$.

Subdivide elements of $P_1$ in half to arrive at a new partition $\mathcal{P}_2$ with lower sum $L_2$ of $\chi_A+\chi_B$. Since $L_1\leq L_2, \mathcal{P}_2$ must also contain some problematic intervals, and every problematic interval of $\mathcal{P}_2$ must be contained in a problematic interval of $\mathcal{P}_1$. Let $P_2$ be the collection of problematic intervals in $\mathcal{P}_2$.

Inductively define $\mathcal{P}_n, L_n, P_n, n\geq 1$. The collection $\cup_{n\geq 1}P_n$ is partially ordered by inclusion and contains chains of any finite length (simply take an element of $P_n$ and go backwards to obtain a chain of length $n$) and finitely many chains of a given length (because each $P_n$ is finite).

Suppose $C_1\supset C_2\supset\dots$ is an infinite chain in $\cup_{n\geq 1}P_n$. Note that each $C_i$ is a problematic interval and since we are halving the lengths, the lengths of these intervals decreases to $0$. Therefore, $\cap_{n\geq 1} C_n$ is a singleton $\{z\}$ (we need an infinite chain for this to work). Since each $C_i$ is problematic, $z\in A\cup B$ and every $C_i$ has a point from $A\setminus B$ and one from $B\setminus A$.

Thus, we have a sequence in $A\setminus B$ converging to $z$ and a sequence in $B\setminus A$ also converging to $z$. Since $z\in A\cup B$, we have a contradiction as $A, B$ are open.

Now, why does an infinite chain exist? See [Given an infinite poset, show that it contains either a infinite chain or an infinite totally unordered set.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519604/given-an-infinite-poset-show-that-it-contains-either-a-infinite-chain-or-an-inf) or [Prove that for any infinite poset there is an infinite subset which is either linearly ordered or antichain.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96436/prove-that-for-any-infinite-poset-there-is-an-infinite-subset-which-is-either-li)

Therefore the lower integrals must be equal.

Comment: It would be interesting to see how much of this depends on choice. Once we have the $P_n$s, I think the existence of an infinite chain doesn't require anything extra because there are infinite maximal chains (for there are chains of arbitrary lengths) and each $P_n$ is finite, so we can inductively construct an infinite chain.